# Selectize for input type="text" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have the following HTML/Bootstrap element:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Keyword:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword">
</div>
```

I want to allow the user to select predefined words as he is typing text into this form using [selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). If no word is selected, then input value is the word user typed in.

How can i do this using selectize.js?

**EDIT:**

The thing is: i need to populate these keyword fields with predefined values extracted from document (i'm actually making an editor), and if i use "select" elements instead of "input", I can't set starting values with:

```
$('#keyword').val();
```

Since these starting values can be random, I cant figure a way to work around this.

Comment: Is there a specific issue you have? If you're asking about how to setup this plugin then all the documentation and example code is available at the link you provided...

Comment: Is there a reason the input has to be of type text?

Comment: I have done it but not with a plug-in, but with ajax php and mysql database. I belive its working well as well.

Comment: Most examples are for <select> form element, but I would like it to be <input type="text">. Is this possible or I need to use <select>?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `create` or `createOnBlur` options on initialization;

Here's the documentation of `selectize.js`

https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md

`create` Allows the user to create new items that aren't in the initial list of options.

`createOnBlur` If true, when user exits the field (clicks outside of input), a new option is created and selected (if create setting is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this:

```
//enable selectize on input element and add a list of options
var $select = $('#keyword').selectize({
maxItems: 1,
valueField: 'id',
labelField: 'title',
searchField: 'title',
options: [
    {id: 1, title: 'value1'},
    {id: 2, title: 'value2'},
    {id: 3, title: 'value3'}
],
create: true,
});

//store selectize object to variable
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
//add new option and set the value to new option
selectize.addOption({id:4, title: 'value4'});
selectize.setValue(4, false);
```

Now the default option after loading the page is 'value4' and other options can be selected as required.